# How to format a date in Laravel using ::lists

Tags: php, arrays, date, laravel-5.1

I am coding a feature in Laravel where a user can use a select box to choose a certain date. By standard, these dates are saved in y-m-d in my table.

I have succeeded in formatting the date to `dd/mm/yyyy` by using the Eloquent solution, adding to my Eloquent Model called Dataslot:

protected $dates = ['maand'];

Afterwards I could use the following to format the date.

```
     $d = Dataslot::find(1);
     $dformat = $d->maand->format('d-m-Y');
```

In order to pass the ID of the dataslot and the date to my select box, I have chosen to use the lists method.

```
$dataslots = Dataslot::lists("maand","id");
```

This returns me an array. I cannot use the format method on this array as I could on the object in the first example.

How can I have an array of formated dates, with the ID as a key, to send to my view?

Answer (score 2):

Untested (I'm on mobile right now) but this should work;

```
Carbon::setToStringFormat('d-m-Y');
$dataslots = Dataslot::lists('maand', 'id');
```

You could change Carbon back after with:

```
Carbon::resetToStringFormat();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it?

```
$dataslots = Dataslots::all()->map(function($dataslot) {
    return [$dataslot->id => $dataslot->maand->format('d-m-Y')];
});
```

Comment: The date is correctly formated.The ID of the dataslot is also added to the value of my select box. Only problem I have now is that an optiongroup label is added automatically, with the key of the array in it.

Comment: @LucasPoignon - that sounds like a problem with the view. Add details in the question, or create a new question. Or if the solution is what you needed, just accept it :)

Comment: Ok I will look a bit further and post a new question if needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick:

```
$dataslots = Dataslot::all();

foreach ($dataslots as $o) {
    $flatArray[$o->id] = $o->maand->format('d-m-Y'); 
}
```